# Comparing 2 tables in different databases and do a delta

Tags: java, sql, database

I have a standalone Java application with embedded H2 Database(D1) and table T1. I have another mysql database(D2) with table T2 hosted on a server. My Requirement is to pull the full data from D2.T2 and push it into D1.T1 . T1 and T2 both have same table definition. First pull is not a problem. Starting from 2nd pull I only need to pull the rows which got updated in D2.T2 and update that in D1.T2 . How can this be achieved? I have to find the delta from the last time i pulled and then update those rows.

Comment: Can you modify the tables to include a hashkey column?

Comment: I cannot modify the table D2.T2. Its our enterprise DB

Answer (score 0):

If the structures on both tables are the same you can try the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO your_table 
    (your_column, ...) 
VALUES 
    (your_value, ...) 
ON DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    your_column = your_value, ...
```

Your have to get the entries from your source database and execute the above statement for each one on your target database.

Comment: They are on two different servers :(

Comment: I think, that is not the Problem. Get the entries in the first step and push it to your target database.